# Doctrine2 raises preFlush too many times (?)

Tags: php, database, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entitymanager

I just noticed strange behavior of Doctrine's event system. In the documentation I read about `preFlush` event:

> `preFlush` is called at `EntityManager#flush()` before anything else

Sounds good. But when I created event subscriber, I saw that something is wrong - `preFlush` occurred twice, while `onFlush` and `postFlush` only once (I'd assumed that `preFlush` also occurs once).

Whats's interesting, `preFlush` is called every time `UnitOfWork` computes changeset - equals number of currently managed entities.

Here's quick example (Doctrine 2.4, I'm not using Symfony):

```
// event subscriber class:

class Subscriber implements EventSubscriber {

    public function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(Events::preFlush, Events::onFlush, Events::postFlush);
    }

    public function preFlush() {
        echo '********** PRE FLUSH ***********' . "\n";
    }

    public function onFlush() {
        echo '********** ON FLUSH ***********' . "\n";
    }

    public function postFlush() {
        echo '********** POST FLUSH ***********' . "\n";
    }

}

// test:

$em->getEventManager()->addEventSubscriber(new Subscriber());

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo 'i = ' . $i . "\n";
    $u = new Unit();  // Unit is sample entity - very simple one with no associations
    $u->setName('unit');
    $u->setSymbol('u');

    $em->persist($u);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Produces output:

```
i = 0
********** PRE FLUSH ***********
********** PRE FLUSH ***********
********** ON FLUSH ***********
********** POST FLUSH ***********
i = 1
********** PRE FLUSH ***********
********** PRE FLUSH ***********
********** PRE FLUSH ***********
********** ON FLUSH ***********
********** POST FLUSH ***********
i = 2
********** PRE FLUSH ***********
********** PRE FLUSH ***********
********** PRE FLUSH ***********
********** PRE FLUSH ***********
********** ON FLUSH ***********
********** POST FLUSH ***********
i = 3
********** PRE FLUSH ***********
********** PRE FLUSH ***********
********** PRE FLUSH ***********
********** PRE FLUSH ***********
********** PRE FLUSH ***********
********** ON FLUSH ***********
********** POST FLUSH ***********
i = 4
********** PRE FLUSH ***********
********** PRE FLUSH ***********
********** PRE FLUSH ***********
********** PRE FLUSH ***********
********** PRE FLUSH ***********
********** PRE FLUSH ***********
********** ON FLUSH ***********
********** POST FLUSH ***********
```

So `preFlush` is called once per each managed entity (including the new one) + once when `EntityManager` actually flushes.

In my opinion `preFlush` event should be called once per `EntityManager#flush()` operation (like other flush events).

I found the code producing that behavior: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L536

Here's my question: Am I wrong, does Doctrine work incorrectly or there's something else I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell if that was intentional or not, but it seems logical.  The number of `PreFlush` calls matches the number of managed entities, but probably because that method is intended to allow you to enforce the entity's integrity.

Notice how the number of `PostFlush` calls doesn't increase.   If each entity's data were to change on flush then `PostFlush` would be called again for each one.

Ideally `$em->flush()` without arguments should only be called at the end of the execution of a script (or very few times at least).  In order to ensure a specific entity is treated and flushed when you invoke it, pass the entity as an argument to the `flush` method.

Comment: Is there any way to abort the flush operation if some condition fails in preFlush() ? Or to call the preFlush listener without invoking ->flush() ?

Answer (score 1):

`preFlush` is triggered for every call to `$em->flush()`. `postFlush` is only triggered if there is an actual changeset to commit. See https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/382 for a discussion on how to change this `postFlush` behaviour.